# Swift SpriteKit how to pause the scene after audio is played completely

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In my Swift file, when func gameOver() is triggered, I will pause the scene.

```
func gameOver() {

        //TODO: play audio explode.mp3
        self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explode", waitForCompletion: true))

        //Pause game
        scene?.isPaused = true

   
}
```

I am expecting the audio will be played first, then the game will be paused.
The problem is game will be paused first, when I restart the game, audio will be played.

Answer (score 0):

The `waitForCompletion` means that the action duration will be the same as the audio file duration, but `run` only schedules actions, it doesn't wait for them to complete.  You can add a completion handler that will be run after the action finishes though.

```swift
    self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explode", waitForCompletion: true)) {
       self.scene?.isPaused = true
    }
```

Comment: Hi @bg2b , this does allow audio to be played first, but the game should be stopped. I tried your code, the game still running while audio is playing. Is there a way to stop/pause the game when playing explode audio?

Comment: You mean you want everything else to stop except for the audio to keep playing?  In general, the `isPaused` property applies to a node and all its children.  So if you want some parts of the scene to pause (the main playfield, e.g.) while other parts continue (e.g., whatever is playing the sound), then one approach is to arrange the hierarchy so that whatever you want to stop is under one parent node and set `isPause` on that.

Comment: Yes, that' what I want. I have two lines of codes above, can u give me an example how to separate these two lines of codes to different node hierarchy ?

Comment: @sky he did already ^ his code is how you pause the game scene once the music is done playing

Comment: Hi @RonMyschuk, I might not say it very clearly, his code plays audio first, then paused the game, however, I want the game to be passed first, and playing audio at the same time.

Comment: If you happen to have arranged things with a single "world" node as a child of the scene node (with all the rest of your game as children of the world node), you can set `isPaused` to `true` on the world node but have the scene run the play sound action.  Or if you don't have that many child nodes of the scene, you can still do it, but you'll have to set `isPaused` for all of them.  The point is that whatever node is going to play the sound (whether that's the scene or some other node) must be unpaused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the music to play but the game to pause you need to layer your game components. For example place all your game components on an sknode called gameLayer, and place all your controls on an SKNode layer called controlsLayer.

Now when you want to pause the game just call

```
gameLayer.isPaused = true
```

now you can still play music in your scene